# how to flattern the nested dict?

Tags: ansible

I have a dict

```
foo:
  a:
    aa1: 1
    aa2: 2
  b:
    bb1: 3
    bb2: 4
```

I want to convert it to:

```
- {key:a, subkey:aa1, value: 1}
- {key:a, subkey:aa2, value: 2}
- {key:b, subkey:bb1, value: 3}
- {key:b, subkey:bb2, value: 4}
```

If it only doable with json_query, I will accept it. But it is preferable not with complicated JMESPath formular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

Use the filter [community.general.dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries)

```yaml
  foo_arr: "{{ foo|ansible.utils.to_paths|dict2items }}"
  foo_key: "{{ foo_arr|map(attribute='key')|map('split', '.') }}"
  foo_val: "{{ foo_arr|map(attribute='value') }}"
  bar: "{{ foo_key|zip(foo_val)|map('flatten')
                  |map('zip', ['key', 'subkey', 'value'])
                  |map('map', 'reverse')
                  |map('community.general.dict') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  bar:
    - {key: a, subkey: aa1, value: 1}
    - {key: a, subkey: aa2, value: 2}
    - {key: b, subkey: bb1, value: 3}
    - {key: b, subkey: bb2, value: 4}
```

Note: This solution is limited to keys without dots.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    foo:
      a:
        aa1: 1
        aa2: 2
      b:
        bb1: 3
        bb2: 4

    foo_arr: "{{ foo|ansible.utils.to_paths|dict2items }}"
    foo_key: "{{ foo_arr|map(attribute='key')|map('split', '.') }}"
    foo_val: "{{ foo_arr|map(attribute='value') }}"
    bar: "{{ foo_key|zip(foo_val)|map('flatten')
                    |map('zip', ['key', 'subkey', 'value'])
                    |map('map', 'reverse')
                    |map('community.general.dict') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: bar|to_yaml
```

---

**origin**

For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        bar: "{{ bar|d([]) + [{'key': _key,
                               'subkey': _sub,
                               'value': _val|int}] }}"
      loop: "{{ foo|ansible.utils.to_paths|dict2items }}"
      vars:
        _arr: "{{ item.key.split('.') }}"
        _key: "{{ _arr.0 }}"
        _sub: "{{ _arr.1 }}"
        _val: "{{ item.value }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  bar:
    - {key: a, subkey: aa1, value: 1}
    - {key: a, subkey: aa2, value: 2}
    - {key: b, subkey: bb1, value: 3}
    - {key: b, subkey: bb2, value: 4}
```

---

Q: *"**Key maybe IP address, thus it breaks.**"*

A: You can easily solve this by indexing, e.g.

```yaml
      vars:
        _arr: "{{ item.key.split('.') }}"
        _key: "{{ _arr[:-1]|join('.') }}"
        _sub: "{{ _arr[-1] }}"
        _val: "{{ item.value }}"
```

The next option is writing a filter. For example, use the filter below and set another *separator*

```py
def dict_flatten(d, separator='.'):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + separator)
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in sorted(x):
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + separator)
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(d)
    return out
```

See the [source code](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/dict_filters/dict_filters.py#L80).

Comment: this seems nice, but my key maybe IP address, thus it breaks.

Comment: I updated the answer. Update indexing, write your own filer or reuse the link I posted.